Internal server error when trying to send an email using Microsoft Graph API
I am trying to send an email using the Microsoft Graph API through the Laravel app; this is the code
$emailData = [
            "message" => [
                "subject" => 'Test', 
                "body" => [
                    "contentType" => "text", 
                    "content" =>  "Test Email!"
                 ], 
                "toRecipients" => [
                    [
                        "emailAddress" => [
                            "address" => "test@gmail.com" 
                        ] 
                    ] 
                ], 
                "from" => [
                        "emailAddress" => [
                            "address" => "test@hotmail.com" 
                        ] 
                ] 
            ]
        ];
       
        $response = Http::withToken($this->token)
            ->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])
            ->post("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test@hotmail.com/sendMail", json_encode($emailData));

I have already obtained access and refresh tokens.
I only get this from response
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInternalServerError","message":"An internal server error occurred. The operation failed."}}

I assume the problem might be with data structure, but I couldn't find it.
Any help is appreciated!

Is this the message that the HTTP request to Graph returns, or an exception which your own PHP code throws? It wasn't clear from your description. If the latter, obviously you should check your PHP error logs in the first instance.

It is response from the Graph API

The problem lies in your HTTP client. Laravel HTTP client automatically handles the encoding of the data as JSON when sending a POST request. So in your case your $emailData is being double encoded since you already passed the json_encode($emailData) to the post(....
Correct syntax would be. Try this.
$response = Http::withToken($this->token)
            ->withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])
            ->post("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/test@hotmail.com/sendMail",[
"key-name"=> $emailData ]);

post(..) accept an array of data as their second argument.For detailed information check the official-docs

It works! Thanks a lot...

welcome, glad to help.
